# ajaxsubmit success function not triggering

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-forms-plugin

Upgrading my wamp server (to 3.0) and php version (5.6) and mySQL (5.7) seems to have broken an app that I have been modifying by guess and by golly for about a year. I'm doing some data retrieval that is obviously successful because refreshing shows the sql being successful, and my json return from the php data feed shows that success.

But the success function is not being triggered, which is supposed to close the dialog and refresh the screen. Therefore I have to close the dialog manually, and there is no refresh.

I would like to try the done() function instead of success, but being a relative newbie, am not aware of how to modify the code to implement that function. When I try it, I get the message "done is not a function", apparently because the jquery.form.js file that I have does not implement the function. Any ideas?

```
var options = {
    beforeSubmit: function() {
        console.log('got to beforesubmit');
        return true;
    },
    dataType: "json",
    type:"POST",
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log('got to success');
        if (data.IsSuccess) {
            CloseModalWindow(null,true);
        }
    }
};

$("#fmEdit").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form){$("#fmEdit").ajaxSubmit(options); 
    },
    errorElement: "div",
    errorClass: "cusErrorPanel",
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        showerror(error, element);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your js doesn't look properly formatted?

This line doesn't look like it should have a semi colon at the end:

```
submitHandler: function(for$("#fmEdit").ajaxSubmit(options);
```

and the `function(for` looks like a copy/paste error.

Comment: Sorry about the copy/past error. This code worked fine before I upgraded. Removing the semicolon produced the same results, no success return.

Comment: Now I'm really confused. Put the semicolon back in, then noticed that I had not changed the datatype back to "json". Did so and everything started working properly. Can't figure out what I did to get it to work.